# Local let like in caml

Tags: rust

I am trying to learn the Rust language and its coding style. I want to use several variables which are independent, but are initialized with the same value which come from a function `f`:

```
let (mut a, mut b) = (f(), f());
```

However, it calls f two times, so it is better to do this:

```
let mut a = f()
let mut b = a
```

Is it possible to do it in one line like in caml?

```ml
let (a,b) = (c,c) where c = f()
(* or *)
let c = f() in let (a,b) = c;
```

Comment: No. Or maybe. Does writing `let a = f(); let b = c;` on one line count? Does writing `let c = f(); let (a, b) = (c, c);` on one line count? What would the advantage of `let in` or `where` be in Rust?

Comment: (actually those would be useful as expressions as in `f(let a = g() in h(a, a))` or whatever, but used as statements like you want to use them, they don't have any advantage)

Comment: It is a more a style question, I wanted to know if there was something similar in Rust. Here it's pure style because it won't change anything. However, as you said, it might be useful in some other cases.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a block to introduce a variable with a restricted scope.

```
let (mut a, mut b) = { let c = f(); (c, c) };
```

Or, more legibly:

```
let (mut a, mut b) = {
    let c = f();
    (c, c)
};
```

Blocks are expressions that evaluate to the last expression in their body, unless that expression is followed by a semicolon, in which case the block evaluates to `()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define trait that converts value to a tuple and implement it for all copyable types:

```
trait AsTuple where Self:Copy{
    #[inline]
    fn as_tuple(self) -> (Self, Self) {(self, self)}
}

impl<T:Copy> AsTuple for T {}



fn get_value() -> u32{
    42
}

fn main() {
    let (a, b) = get_value().as_tuple();
    println!("{} {}", a,b);
}
```

Similarly, you can make a trait to call a function with the same arguments:

```
trait ApplySame where Self:Copy{
    #[inline]
    fn apply_same<R, F: Fn(Self, Self) -> R>(self, f:F) -> R {f(self,self)}
}

impl<T:Copy> ApplySame for T {}

fn sum_it(a:u16, b: u16) -> u16 { a + b }

fn print_me(a:u8, b:u8){
    println!("a:{}, b:{}", a, b);
}

fn get_value() -> u16 { 21 }

fn main() {
    println!("{}", get_value().apply_same(sum_it));
    1u8.apply_same(print_me);
}
```

Comment: Why use a trait for that? You could as well have written `as_2tuple(get_value())` with `fn as_2tuple<T>(v: T) -> (T, T) { (v, v) }`.

Comment: A trait allows to use method syntax call

Comment: if I understand your point correctly, you never write any free function and always make dummy traits just to use method call syntax?

Comment: @mcarton It seems I do not understand your point of view.
Which traits are "dummy" and which are not? 
This particular trait does exactly what Traits are used. It provides new functionality for the type for which it is implemented.
Of course pointless to make a fuss if you need to copy a value once.
However syntactically this method is much more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, but don't do it.

- If your goal really is to write it on one line, just write `let a = f(); let b = a;` on one line.
- If your goal is to have a `let in` expression, you can do that with a block:

```
f({ let a = g(); h(a, a) });
```

would be equivalent to ocaml:

```
f(let a = g() in h(a, a));
```

None of them are really idiomatic though.